# Why execution time in Python gives different results at each run?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of one column having positive and negative values. I want to find index position of negative values. I have two methods here and I am trying to find which of the methods is best and fastest. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'Current': [1, 3, -4, 9, -3, 1, -2]})

# Method-1
start1 = time.time()
neg_index1 = df[(df["Current"]<0)].index.tolist()
print(neg_index1)
end1 = time.time()
print("Method-1 time is = ",end1 - start1)

# Method-2
start2 = time.time()
neg_index2 = df.iloc[df["Current"].lt(0).values].index.tolist()
print(neg_index2)
end2 = time.time()
print("Method-2 time is = ",end2 - start2)
```

Output at first execution and Method-2 is faster here:

```
[2, 4, 6]
Method-1 time is =  0.002000093460083008 
[2, 4, 6]
Method-2 time is =  0.0009999275207519531
```

Output at second execution and interestingly both clock same time:

```
[2, 4, 6]
Method-1 time is =  0.0009999275207519531
[2, 4, 6]
Method-2 time is =  0.0009999275207519531
```

Output at fourth execution and surprisingly Method-1 is faster here:

```
[2, 4, 6]
Method-1 time is =  0.0009999275207519531
[2, 4, 6]
Method-2 time is =  0.0019998550415039062
```

Some explanation and help to know which method is faster?

Comment: It depends some time on the other proceses that the processor get scheduled by the operating system. so if there are other processes invoked by operating system and your processors are busy then these type of situation appears.

Comment: you may want to run  this in an virtual env and see if it changes execution time as the resources will be much more focused as compared to non virtual env.

Comment: Don't use `time.time` to benchmark things; use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module. There are a number of good reasons for that, but it's hard to beat the fact that you're trying to measure something that takes 1-2ms with a clock with a 1ms resolution, which means you've got error bars of +/-100%…

Comment: @durjoy, Glad to receive your inputs. Due to my non-computer background, I did not understood what is said here. Please, help me with some code.

Comment: @Anil_M, Glad to receive your inputs. Due to my non-computer background, I did not understood what is said here. Please, help me with some code

Comment: @abarnert, How to use `timeit` function? Some code please?

Comment: If you can't understand the examples in the docs I linked to, I have no idea what I could put into a StackOverflow comment that would help.

Comment: @Msquare `np.where` is the fastest (by far)

Comment: @Msquare My answer runs ten times with `timeit`

Comment: @Msquare https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279965/what-is-the-explication-for-the-difference-execution-time-for-the-same-instructi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(df['Current']<0)[0].tolist()
```

Also don't use `time.time` use `timeit`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({'Current': [1, 3, -4, 9, -3, 1, -2]})

# Method-1
neg_index1 = df[(df["Current"]<0)].index.tolist()
print(neg_index1)
print("Method-1 time is = ",timeit.timeit(lambda: df[(df["Current"]<0)].index.tolist(),number=10))

# Method-2
neg_index2 = df.iloc[df["Current"].lt(0).values].index.tolist()
print(neg_index2)
print("Method-2 time is = ",timeit.timeit(lambda: df.iloc[df["Current"].lt(0).values].index.tolist(),number=10))

# Method-3
neg_index2 = np.where(df['Current']<0)[0].tolist()
print(neg_index2)
print("Method-3 time is = ",timeit.timeit(lambda: np.where(df['Current']<0)[0].tolist(),number=10))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6]
Method-1 time is =  0.0211404744016608
[2, 4, 6]
Method-2 time is =  0.02377961247025239
[2, 4, 6]
Method-3 time is =  0.007515077367731743
```

So `np.where` wins big time!

Comment: Excellent. You are simply superb for introducing me a new method-3. I executed it many times. Your are on spot and it is fastest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you give me some explanation about `[0]` in `np.where(df['Current']<0)[0]`. I mean, what it is referring to ?

Comment: @Msquare `numpy.where` returns (in this case) `(array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int64),)` (a tuple) so get first (zeroth) element, then do `tolist`

Comment: That was not my question. My question is, why do we need to use `[0]` at end of `np.where(df['Current']<0)[0]`?

Comment: @Msquare You need because `np.where` returns a tuple with only one element (the array) so get the first (zeroth) element

Comment: I got it now. Thanks

Comment: @Msquare Happy you understand, 

Comment: What happens if we put `[1]` instead of `[0]` at end of a tuple? I mean, is it right ?

Comment: @Msquare Then it will raise an error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: 1. `print("\n\n",np.where(df['Current']<0))`, Output: `(array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int64),)` This is a tuple output? Am I right?,    2. `print(np.where(df['Current']<0)[0])` Output : `[2 4 6]` What is the type/name of this output ?  
3. `print(np.where(df['Current']<0)[0].tolist())` Output: `[2,4,6]`. This is a list. I got it.

Comment: @Msquare What you mean by called?

Comment: I mean, what is the data type of this output?

Comment: @Msquare it's a list

Comment: `[2,4,6]` I hope! this is a list.  But, `[2 4 6]` has no `,` between values. Is this still be  a list?

Comment: @Msquare No, that's a numpy array

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to ask. Good. I got it. Now, `(array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int64),)` is a tuple. `[2 4 6]` is a numpy array. `[2,4,6]` is a list. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for educating me this small and basic topics. I started learning python one month ago. I learned the difference between the three here. Thanks a lot for your patience. I am wondering! how did you learn these tricks of python? what is your source of learning? how much time did it took you to reach this stage?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i was learning some stuff from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/), it took me around a year to get to this stage, but also i had a lot of help form other people around me, also learned a lot from stackoverflow, seeing other answers, also i learn while answering questions, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There could be other processes consuming resources while you are measuring the time taken for each execution. There could also be garbage collector kicking in at random points skewing up the results. So never use `time.time()` for comparing performance.

Use the `timeit.timeit` for measuring performance. It repeats the code run several times and measures average time taken for each run, thus providing much more acurate results. It also disables garbage collection during the run.